# Call function, object attributes, or modules using a list of strings

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of module names:

```
md = ['md1','md2','md3']
```

Each modules has a class named `object` with attribute `name`:

```
class object:
    name = 'obj'
```

In the other script, I would like to output all the attribute values of class `object` from all modules (assumes I had imported it):

```
for x in md:
    print(x.object.name)
```

What I'm expected is:

```
# Attribute values from class 'object' from all modules
obj
obj
obj
```

But when I try this, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: But `.format()` comes with `str` Eg. `("{}".format(module_name)).split()`

Comment: @Leo this solved my problem, thanks! :D

Comment: @Leo but I still can't call object attributes what I am use is `('{}'.format('test')).a` (assume I have object `test` with attribute `a`), any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`format` comes under `str`. 
This will work.
`('{}'.format(module_name)).split)`

Comment: Same as comment above but also solved my problem too! Thanks! :D

Comment: edit: Just now didn't notice the output, actually the interpreter called built-in function `split` but not `re.split()`, any ideas?

Comment: just check `type('{}'.format(re))`   `type('{}'.format(re).split)`,  and  `type(re)`, `type(re.split)`,   you will get your answer. :)

Comment: Pardon me, but I still don't understand your meaning, `type()` only output its types, but I wanted is to call the function. I will edit my question to clarify my question properly.

Comment: There are two `split` function, one from `str` class  that is built-in function and another one is from `re` module. I guess you are trying to access `re` module's `split` function. But once you  use `format` on module `re` it become `str` class object, so when you perform `split` on it, it returns `str` 's built-in function.

Comment: I updated my question with what I wanted to achieve, maybe this will help you understand my question.

Comment: `for x in md: ` check here what is `type` of `x` . I guess here your `x` is `str` not `module`

Answer (score 0):

It's quite ambiguous what you are trying to achieve. If you are trying to use `attribute` of the `function` you need to import it. `.format()` is used for string `str` formatting.

```
import re
re.search('(?<=abc)def', 'abcdef')
```

This will give a function object.

Comment: But this only do the search, and will not call it.